# Changing the time series of 8 digits to Date

Tags: r, date

I have tried to convert 19880705 into Date. With many functions, they still appear NA.

```
data$X <- as.Date(data$X,strptime(data$X,format="%d/%m/%Y"),format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

I install `lubridate`, and tried the below and still NA.

```
parse_date_time(as.Date(data$X), "%Y%m%d").
```

Comment: `lubridate::ymd` perhaps? Otherwise, it seems you want to do it with a purely `base` approach.

Comment: looks like your dates are formatted as `"%Y%m%d"`, not as `"%d/%m/%Y"`

Answer (score 1):

Actually `as.Date` should be working, assuming you are trying to use it on a string input:

```
x <- 19880705
as.Date(as.character(x), format="%Y%m%d")
[1] "1988-07-05"
```

On the other hand, this won't work

```
as.Date(x, format="%Y%m%d")
```

In this case, R won't even recognize the input `x` as being the input, it will mistake it as the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The [anytime](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) package was written to make this automagic by not requiring formats and taking care of all obvious conversions.

```
R> anytime::anydate(19880705)  
[1] "1988-07-05"  
R>
```

There are converters for datetimes and date, optionally with UTC adjustment, some formatting helpers and more.  See the [repo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime) for a brief overview.